# Remove names from a column of numbers (which are strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column of strings that contains ID numbers but some of the rows contain different names which I don't need

Ex:

```
12-1
name
12-2
name
12-3
```

sometimes the ID numbers are just numbers (contain no dashes)

```
12
name
13
name
14
```

I'd like the output to be

```
12-1
12-2
12-3
```

or

```
12
13
14
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this besides removing the dashes when they are present, converting to numeric, coerce errors and then removing rows with nan in them?

Comment: `series[series.str.contains('\d')]` ?

Comment: There is many solutions, question is how `hard` are rules for matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. using `query`  and `str.isalpha`:

```
df.query('~col1.str.isalpha()')
```

**Output**

```
   col1
0  12-1
2  12-2
4  12-3
```

---

#### 2. Using `str.contains` with the regex `or` operator:

```
df[df['col1'].str.contains('[\d|\d-]')]
```

**Output**

```
   col1
0  12-1
2  12-2
4  12-3
```

---

#### 3. Using `replace` with `isnumeric`:

```
df[df['col1'].str.replace('-', '').str.isnumeric()]
```

**Output**

```
   col1
0  12-1
2  12-2
4  12-3
```

---

**Test dataframe**

```
    col1
0   12-1
1   name
2   12-2
3   name
4   12-3
5  name-
6      -
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
    col
0  12-1
1  name
2  12-2
3  name
4    12
```

You can filter all rows if any number in `col` column:

```
df = df[df['col'].str.contains('\d')]
```

Or more explicit is possible test if only number or only number with `-`:

```
print (df)
         col
0      name1
1        45-
2       12-1
3       name
4       12-2
5  name12-23
6         12

df = df[df['col'].str.contains('^\d+$|^\d+-\d+$')]
#if need match 45-
#df = df[df['col'].str.contains('^\d+-?$|^\d+-\d+$')]
print (df)
    col
2  12-1
4  12-2
6    12
```